# i got this error when i run any project in flutter (Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception)

Tags: flutter

```
/C:/Users/New%201000%20Mezza/Downloads/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:5210:14: Error: Expected ';' after this.
      } else phase if (owner!._debugStateLocked) {
             ^^^^^
/C:/Users/New%201000%20Mezza/Downloads/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:5210:14: Error: The getter 'phase' isn't defined for the class 'Element'.
```

- 'Element' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/Users/New%201000%20Mezza/Downloads/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'phase'.
  } else phase if (owner!._debugStateLocked) {
  ^^^^^
  Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Users\New 1000 Mezza\Downloads\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 52s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

> Exited (1).`your text`

i try `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get` then `dart fix --apply` and didnot work . i work in vs code and i did many project before put i get this error for 2 days and i try to solved